# How can i force laravel nova to compile the new modified custom field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have installed a new custom field from nova packages website.

I have some modifications in this js/component file and I have saved the file.

Now I don't know how I can force nova laravel to use the modified js/component file because I have refreshed the page with no success.

I have follwed those steps and still no results:

- https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/frontend.html#vue-devtools

Please mind, I'm a beginner and I need step by step instructions.

Comment: On first glance, this appears to me like a caching problem. Have you tried clearing the cache and/or disabled it? The development tools in the browser normally allow you to explicitly disable caches under the _Network_ settings/tab.